# How to set the identifier of AVMetadataItem in swift3?

Tags: swift, swift3, tvos, avmetadataitem

### Description:

I'm attempting to set the `identifier` of `AVMetadataItem` in `swift3`, like mentioned in [this apple video](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2016/506ms2tv71tcduwp3dm/506/hls_vod_mvp.m3u8). However, the video is pre-swift3.

In `swift2` it would look something like this:

```
let metadataItem = AVMetadataItem(identifier: AVMetadataCommonIdentifierTitle, value: "Title here")
```

However, in `swift3` that constructor does not exist anymore.

There is an empty constructor and this one:

```
AVMetadataItem(propertiesOf: AVMetadataItem, valueLoadingHandler: (AVMetadataItemValueRequest) -> Void)
```

There does not seem to be any methods that exist to set the `identifier`.

### Question:

How do I set the `identifier` of `AVMetadataItem` in `swift3`?

### Edit:

Tried with AVMutableMetadataItem() as suggested by Lucas.

```
private func setupNavigationMarker(title: String, description: String, timeRange: CMTimeRange)-> AVTimedMetadataGroup {
    var items: [AVMetadataItem] = []
    let titleItem =  AVMutableMetadataItem()
    titleItem.identifier = AVMetadataCommonIdentifierTitle
    titleItem.value = title as (NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol)?
    items.append(titleItem)

    let descriptionItem = AVMutableMetadataItem()
    descriptionItem.identifier = AVMetadataCommonIdentifierDescription
    descriptionItem.value = description as (NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol)?
    items.append(descriptionItem)

    return AVTimedMetadataGroup(items: items, timeRange: timeRange)

}
```

and here in use:

```
    let cmTimeStart = CMTimeMake(0, 0)
    let cmTimeDuration = CMTimeMake(10, 1)

    let timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: cmTimeStart, duration: cmTimeDuration)

    let timedMetadataGroup = self.setupNavigationMarker(title: "test", description: "description test" , timeRange: timeRange)
    let timedMetadataGroupList = [timedMetadataGroup]
    let navigationMarkersGroup = AVNavigationMarkersGroup(title: "Chapters", timedNavigationMarkers: timedMetadataGroupList)
    //predefined avPlayerItem
    avPlayerItem.navigationMarkerGroups.append(navigationMarkersGroup)
```

It compiles and runs but no navigation markers (aka chapters) are proposed when the video plays. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `AVMutableMetadata` instead of `AVMetadata` this way you can modify the `identifier` as you choose to.

```
let titleItem =  AVMutableMetadataItem()
titleItem.identifier = AVMetadataCommonIdentifierTitle
```

Comment: Have you try using AVMutableMetadataItem instance? "To create metadata items for your own assets, you use the mutable subclass, AVMutableMetadataItem."

Comment: @LucasDavanzo I actually have not. I'll play around with it and see if it works. Thanks for the advice.